# count unique values between defined range in column

Tags: excel, range, unique

I've got column which consist numbers of type 000.XX.XX

=COUNTIFS(temporary!$A1:$A200,">=000.11.35",temporary!$A1:$A200,"<=000.11.39")
this formula counts values between 000.11.35 and 000.11.39. But i want to count only unique values. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built-in function for this, as you can see from the several suggestions of how to accomplish this on the [Office support site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273). If you can, you can switch to Google Sheets, and they have a "COUNTUNIQUE()" function.

As described at the link provided above, identify the unique items, either using a filer (this is static) or through repeatedly using the "FREQUENCY()" function. Then count the unique items in a separate step.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have the data set in the first column, first you need to remove the repetitions in a second column with the following array formula (confirm the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

=IF(SUM((A2=$A$2:A2)*1)>1,"",A2)

this formula lists only unique values
I would remove your first 4 digits of your string to create a float number and then count it with the following array formula:

=SUM((IF((RIGHT($B$2:$B$14,4)>=RIGHT(G3,4))*(RIGHT($B$2:$B$14,4)<=RIGHT(G4,4)),$B$2:$B$14,"")<>"")*1)

Please look at the two images for clarification

[view with formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMVu0.png)
[normal printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYHoc.png)